# Cannot find # in OpenSearch query

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I have an index that includes a field and when a '#' is input, I cannot get the query to find the #.

Field Data: `"#3213939"`

Query:

```
GET /invoices/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "referenceNumber": {
              "query": "#32"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "referenceNumber": {
              "value": "*#32*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"#" character drops during standard text analyzer this is why you can't find it.

```
POST _analyze
{
  "text": ["#3213939"]
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "3213939",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

You can update the analyzer and customize it.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html

OR

you can use `referenceNumber.keyword` field.

```
GET test_invoices/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        
        {
          "match": {
            "referenceNumber": {
              "query": "#32"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "referenceNumber.keyword": {
              "value": "*#32*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```